# How to create a pandas DatetimeIndex with year as frequency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date-range

Using the `pandas.date_range(startdate, periods=n, freq=f)` function you can create a range of pandas `Timestamp` objects where the `freq` optional paramter denotes the frequency (second, minute, hour, day...) in the range.

The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) does not mention the literals that are expected to be passed in, but after a few minutes you can easily find most of them.

- 's' : second
- 'min' : minute
- 'H' : hour
- 'D' : day
- 'w' : week
- 'm' : month

However, none of 'y', 'Y', 'yr', etc. create dates with year as frequency.
Does anybody know what to pass in, or if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## Annual indexing to the beginning or end of the year

Frequency is `freq='A'` for end of year frequency, `'AS'` for start of year. Check the [aliases in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases).

eg. `pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2000, 1, 1), periods=4, freq='A')`

returns

`DatetimeIndex(['2000-12-31', '2001-12-31', '2002-12-31', '2003-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='A-DEC', tz=None)`

## Annual indexing to the beginning of an arbitrary month

If you need it to be annual from a particular time use an [anchored offset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets),
eg. `pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2000, 1, 1), periods=10, freq='AS-AUG')`

returns

`DatetimeIndex(['2000-08-01', '2001-08-01', '2002-08-01', '2003-08-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='AS-AUG', tz=None)`

## Annual indexing from an arbitrary date

To index from an arbitrary date, begin the series on that date and use a custom [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) object.

eg. `pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2000, 9, 10), periods=4, freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))`

returns

`DatetimeIndex(['2000-09-10', '2001-09-10', '2002-09-10', '2003-09-10'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: kwds={'years': 1}>', tz=None)`

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why the documentation page of `date_range()` is not linking to this page, would have saved me from posting this question.

Comment: Is it possible to use a custom day, like 1st Aug?

Comment: Thanks, at least works for the 1st of a certain month.

Comment: I feel like I'm just rewriting the docs now, but I've updated for an arbitrary date.

Comment: how could you get the last business day of a custom month? i have `df1 = df1.set_index(pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(1984,1,1),end=pd.datetime(2015,1,1), freq='A-JUN')'` but want the last business day of June

Comment: Note that `pd.date_range` accepts strings coercible to date (anything `pd.Timestamp` can be constructed from) for dates. So you can use `start='2001-8-1'` for a start date of August 1, 2001.

Answer (score 5):

With all those hacks, there is a clear way:

```
pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime.now(),periods=5,freq='A')
```

`A` :  Annually.

`365D`? Really? What about [leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use month and then pick every 12th month:

```
months=pandas.date_range(start=datetime.datetime.now(),periods=120,freq='M')
year=[months[11*i] for i in range(12)]
```

You can also do:

```
usingDays=pandas.date_range(start=datetime.datetime.now(),periods=10,freq='365D')
```

but that won't work so well with leap years.

Comment: For the above to work you would have to `import datetime` but if you have a specific start date in mind then you can also use that.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use multiples for the frequency strings.  For example:

```
pd.date_range('01/01/2010',periods=10,freq='365D')
```

This code will give you a series with 01/01/2010, 01/01/2011, etc., which I think is what you are looking for. Of course, the issue here is that you will run into problems with leap years.

Comment: I have actually tried to pass in '12m' for 12 months, but that isn't right, e.g. first date is 2015-01-01, the next will be 2016-01-31. The 365 aren't right either, leap years.